# Игнорирование папок при рекурсивном поиске файла

Tags: c++

Необходимо модифицировать функцию рекурсивного поиска файла, чтобы она могла принимать в себя вектор с папками, в которые программа заходить **не** должна. Но возникает проблема с тем, что он или игнорирует это, или выбрасывает ошибку рантайма или памяти. Используется **recursive_directory_iterator** из **filesystem**.
Функция поиска:

```
vector<fs::path> FindFileRecursively(const wstring& fileName, const wstring& parentDirectory, const vector<fs::path> excludedFolders)
{
    vector<fs::path> results;
    fs::path startPath(parentDirectory + L'\\');

    if(!fs::is_directory(fs::path(parentDirectory)))
    {
        return vector<fs::path>(0);
    }
    for(auto file = fs::recursive_directory_iterator(startPath, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied | fs::directory_options::follow_directory_symlink);
        file != fs::recursive_directory_iterator(); file++)
    {
        if (!excludedFolders.empty())
        {
            wstring parentPath = file->path().wstring();

            for (auto& excl : excludedFolders)
            {
                if (parentPath + L"\\" == excl)
                {
                    file.disable_recursion_pending();
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        wstring foundFileName = ToUpperWstring(file->path().filename().wstring());
        if (foundFileName.find(ToUpperWstring(fileName)) != wstring::npos)
        {
            results.push_back(move(file->path().wstring()));
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Функция запроса папок:

```
vector<fs::path> GetExcludedFolders()
{
    vector<fs::path> excludedFolders;
    wstring currentInput;
    do
    {
        getline(wcin, currentInput);
        
        if(currentInput.empty() || !CheckWrongCharacters(currentInput))
        {
            break;
        }
        
        excludedFolders.push_back(fs::path(currentInput + L"\\"));
    }
    while (!currentInput.empty() && CheckWrongCharacters(currentInput));

    vector<fs::path> subFolders = excludedFolders;
    for (auto& folder: subFolders)
    {
        for (auto& file : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(folder, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied | fs::directory_options::follow_directory_symlink))
        {
            if (file.is_directory())
            {
                excludedFolders.push_back(file.path());
            }
        }
    }


    return excludedFolders;
}
```

Comment: Возможно (*C++  дурацкий язык (при возможности не пользуйтесь им, ошибок и мутоты с отладкой будет в разы меньше)), сложно ясно представить, как именно провзаимодействуют компоненты  его stl:: в неоднозначной ситуации*) вот тут `results.push_back(move(file->path().wstring()));` не надо использовать `move()`. Попробуйте не экономить память. Кстати, imho такое использование `.find()` будет находить не только искомый файл, но и все имена, где он будет подстрокой

Comment: @avp, так и нужно, чтобы искалась подстрока, проблема то не в этом. Он выбрасывает ошибку рантайма при работе, при вводе диска C: он просто ломается

Comment: Если move убрать, то тоже падает?

Comment: @avp, проверю это. Но когда я проверял отладчиком, на диске C: он выбрасывал исключение от несанкционированного чтения памяти (access violation)

Comment: Тогда вы уже знаете, где именно искать. Я с этой конкретной отладкой не помогу, винды у меня нет

Comment: @avp, убрать move не помогло

Comment: А где именно валится?

Comment: Когда дело доходит до диска C:

Comment: Ну, я имел в виду, на какой строке падает, какие там значения переменных и т.д. (вы же ее отладчиком смотрели)